# Does the HTTP protocol allow for the response body to be partially received as a stream?

Tags: swift, http, networking

I stumbled upon a new method within Apple's Swift Foundation framework that allows me to receive the response body of an HTTP response as a stream, I can get it line by line.

```
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767351-bytes
```

But if the HTTP response body is usually compressed, let's say gzip, and the compression applies to the entirety of the body, how can I receive a streaming response, decompression would not be possible as I'm missing data, I've just received partial data.

So is the API provided just gives me a stream of the full data already downloaded or how does it work, which of my assumptions are wrong.

I would like, in theory to receive a stream of data, and then stop half way when relevant data is found, saving internet bandwidth.

Comment: Yeah just cancel the task when you get what you want but the API would have to give you partial data or “chunks”

Comment: HTTP doesn’t concern itself with whether you read the entire response, but if you don’t, the sender will get a connection reset and you won’t be able to use HTTP keepalive. Or else the API you’re using may read it all anyway.